# Get list of Character represent-able on specific culture keyboard in C#

Tags: c#

I want to check if we can type a specific character through keyboard (unicode characters) in specific culture. For example, in United-State English Language I can type which characters through keyboard. 
Another example, In German Language keyboard we can type á or Á.. Is there any way to check?
I have tried this code..

```
  Enumerable.Range(32, char.MaxValue - 32)
                .Select(n => (char)n)
                .Where(c => IsRepresentable(c, 
  keyboardLayout));

static bool IsRepresentable(char c, IntPtr keyboardLayout) 
{ 
    var x = Api.VkKeyScanEx(c, keyboardLayout); 
    int a = 0; 
    return x != -1; 
}
```

But this code not working for dead keys. For example, ò, Ò ,ô ,Ô, ß, ä, Ä.

Comment: Can you add code for `IsRepresentable`?

Comment: static bool IsRepresentable(char c, IntPtr keyboardLayout)
        {
            var x = Api.VkKeyScanEx(c, keyboardLayout);
            int a = 0;
            return x != -1;
        }

Comment: @MobeenGhaffar Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: @MobeenGhaffar Not sure if you lost track of your earlier question but this one appears to be an almost identical question to the one you asked the previous day. You can go there to check answers and to provide feedback: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61835694/list-of-all-possible-input-characters-from-specific-language-keyboard-including